# Fetch Twitter ID

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

How to fetch Twitter data from multiple Tweet IDs using Twitter API?

It is showing
{"errors":[{"message":"You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve","code":453}]}

Is there any way to fetch with only having essential access ?

Answer (score 0):

As said try applying for elevated access via the Developer portal.

As soon as you get the access, you'll be able to fetch the data from Twitter API's itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).